# Can the fix point set of a nontrivial irreducible complex representation of a finite odd order group be non trivial?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm trying to show that if $G$ is a finite odd order group then, all of its  nontrivial complex representations are of complex type (i.e., it is not realisable over the reals).

(I have answered it here: [If $G$ is a finite non-trivial group of odd order, it has an irreducible representation not realisable over the reals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033844/if-g-is-a-finite-non-trivial-group-of-odd-order-it-has-an-irreducible-represe/3073479#3073479))

Let $V$ be such a representation, and let $V^G:=\{v\in V: gv=v, \forall g \in G\}$ be its fix point set. Using some theorems in Bröcker's book about Representations of Compact Lie Groups, I can solve this problem if I show that $V^G=0$. Is that true?

Comment: Well, what about the trivial representation?

Comment: It should be a non-trivial representation*, I'll change @MattSamuel

Comment: I have answered the first question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033844/if-g-is-a-finite-non-trivial-group-of-odd-order-it-has-an-irreducible-represe/3073479#3073479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any nonzero vector $v\in V^G$ spans a $1$-dimensional trivial sub-representation. If $V$ is irreducible of dimension $>1$, then it follows that $V^G=0$. If $\dim V=1$, then $V^G\neq 0$ implies $V$ is the trivial representation.